# Copying Memory Pages in SLES Linux is much faster then in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, performance, memory, kernel, cpu

I have two virtual machines running on the exact same Hardware. One of them is SLES12SP5 (Kernel 4.12) (I have similar results with SLES15SP2, but got no at hand at the moment) and one of them is Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.4). I have a really simple C-Program which measures writing into allocated memory pages and copying them. This program is WAY faster on SLES then on Ubuntu and I can't figure out why. Unfortunately I can't activate the performance counters on the esx Host because of the cluster configuration, maybe that would help to find out whats happening here.

Okay, so here is the Programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __linux__
#include <sys/time.h>
#elif _WIN32
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#endif

#ifdef __linux__
double get_time_insec() {
    struct timeval tstruct;

    gettimeofday(&tstruct, NULL);
    long long milliseconds = tstruct.tv_sec*1000LL + tstruct.tv_usec/1000;
    return (double)milliseconds/1000;
}
#elif _WIN32
double get_time_insec() {
    struct timeb tstruct;

    ftime(&tstruct);
    return (double)tstruct.time + ((double)tstruct.millitm / (double)1000);
}
#endif

#define PAGESIZE 8 * 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int     i = 0;
    int     x = 0;
    double  startval = 0;
    int     pagenum = 0;
    int     offset = 0;
    int     numOfPages = 0;
    int     numOfTimes = 0;
    size_t  allocBytes = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
         printf("Usage %s numOfPages numOfTimes\n", argv[0]);
         return -1;
    }

    numOfPages = atoi(argv[1]);
    numOfTimes = atoi(argv[2]);
    allocBytes = numOfPages*PAGESIZE*2;

    // Allocate memory Pages
    printf("Allocating %ld Bytes\n", allocBytes);
    char *mymem = malloc(allocBytes);

    if (mymem == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Fill the first half of Pages with text
    printf("Filling %d Pages %d times...", numOfPages, numOfTimes);
    fflush(stdout);
    startval = get_time_insec();
    for (x = 0; x < numOfTimes; x++) {
        for (pagenum = 0; pagenum < numOfPages; pagenum++) {
            for (i = 0; i < PAGESIZE; i += 32) {
                offset = (pagenum * PAGESIZE) + i;
                memcpy(mymem + offset, &"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456", 32);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Time taken: %.6f sec\n", get_time_insec() - startval);

    // And now copy them to the next half of pages
    printf("Copying %d Pages %d times...", numOfPages/2, numOfTimes);
    fflush(stdout);
    startval = get_time_insec();
    for (x = 0; x < numOfTimes; x++) {
        for (pagenum = 0; pagenum < numOfPages; pagenum++) {
            memcpy((mymem + (numOfPages/2) * PAGESIZE) + (pagenum * PAGESIZE), mymem + (pagenum * PAGESIZE), PAGESIZE);
        }
    }
    printf("Time taken: %.6f sec\n", get_time_insec() - startval);

    free(mymem);

    return 0;
}
```

And this are the results for running it with "2000 200":

Ubuntu:

```
Filling 2000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.606000 sec
Copying 1000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.921000 sec
```

SLES:

```
Filling 2000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.513000 sec
Copying 1000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.479000 sec
```

I can't get my head around why SLES is twice as fast then Ubuntu.
I thought that writing into memory is a operation where the os doesn't do anything, apart from allocating the pages in the MMU beforehand.
So why exactly could it be that SLES is twice as fast?
Any kernel parameter? Any parameter in the virtual memory subsystem?

I would love to solve this which is bugging me for weeks now!

Thomas

Comment: First of all, you should check the generated binaries are the same. To do that, you can try to use the same compiler with the same version or compile the program once and then run the same binary on the two environments. Moreover, you should check the versions of the libc used are the same or comparable (for memcpy). If this is not coming from the above points, then you can try different kernels to track the regression.

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely right. After compiling the source directly on the platform and activating the gcc Optimizations the values are very close now:

Ubuntu:

```
Filling 2000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.208000 sec
Copying 1000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.484000 sec
```

SLES:

```
Filling 2000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.205000 sec
Copying 1000 Pages 200 times...Time taken: 0.470000 sec
```

I think I can live with that. Of course Ubuntu is still slower then SLES every time, but it's such a minimal difference that it won't matter much!

Thanks a lot for your help !

Thomas